# How to set songs from tableview to notification sound in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I am adding 3 .wav files in my resources folder. Then I am fetching all the 3 songs in an array .IN the didselectRowatIndexPath of this class. I am setting the array to an nsstring variable. In this nsstring variable the song that I have selected its filepath is getting stored and I am accessing this nsstring variable in my class where I am scheduling notification and in it notification.soundname property I am setting the variable where the song filepath is getting stored.

But the problem is when the notification is received that particular song does not play instead the default notification sound is played. What may be the problem? This is my code.

This is my class where I am selecting the songs:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //this is used to search all the song files with wav extension in the resources folder.
    app = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    soundarray = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathsForResourcesOfType:@".wav" inDirectory:nil]retain];
    tblView.delegate = self;
    tblView.dataSource = self;



}


#pragma mark - UITableView, UITableViewDataSource delegate.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [soundarray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = [soundarray objectAtIndex:0]; 
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = [soundarray objectAtIndex:1];
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.textLabel.text =[soundarray objectAtIndex:2];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [soundarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    app.newsong = [soundarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [delegate selectsoundControllerReturnedsound:app.newsong forIndexPath:self.indexPathToChange];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and the class where I am scheduling the notification I have accesed my app delegate string variable where the sound filepath is getting stored.

```
notification.soundName = app.newsong;
```

But the notification shows up with the default notification sound.

This is the code for scheduling notification

```
-(void)scheduleNotification

{
    //itemDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    timepicker = [[TTimePickerController alloc]init];

    double double_date = (double)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];     

      NSDate *now= [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:double_date];
    selectedWeek = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"weekday"];
    //NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"time"];
    //NSDate *testdate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"time" ];
    NSInteger repeatCount = 7;
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *date1;
    NSString *Stringdate;
    calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateFormatter *format = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    format.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    dateFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";

    NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    timeFormat.dateFormat = @"hh:mm";

    for (NSDate *date in array)

    {
        if ([date isEqualToDate:now]) 
        {
            itemDate = date;
            //app.timerdate = date;
            NSLog(@"%@",itemDate);
        } 
        else if([date earlierDate:now]){
            itemDate = date;

            //app.timerdate = date;

        }
        else if([date laterDate:now])
        {
            itemDate = date;

            //app.timerdate =date;
        }

    }

        UILocalNotification *notification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease]; 
    {
            BOOL idGenereated=FALSE;
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < repeatCount; i++) 
        {

            date1 = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:i*24*60*60];
            dateComponents  =[calendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date1];
            if ([selectedWeek containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:dateComponents.weekday - 1]]) {
                Stringdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date1 ],[timeFormat stringFromDate:itemDate]];

                //this line has been commented becuase alarmid was not getting generated
                //if ([today compare:[format dateFromString:Stringdate]] ==NSOrderedAscending)
//              {
                    notification.fireDate = itemDate;
                    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                    notification.alertBody = @"Alarm";
                    notification.alertAction = @"View";
                    //notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                    //notification.soundName = @"Boat Coast Guard, sirens 1 1.wav";
                    notification.soundName = app.newsong;
                    NSLog(@"notification sound name:%@",notification.soundName);
                    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber=1;
                    notification.repeatInterval = 0;
                    notification.alertBody = @"Alarm date";
                    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
                    NSString *str_alarmbody = notification.alertBody; 
                    NSString *str_id = [[str_alarmbody componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:1];
                    NSLog(@"Notif userinfo:%@",str_id);
                    NSLog(@"%@",notification.alertBody);
                    //NSString *firstLetter;

                    if(!idGenereated)
                    {
                        NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
                        NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt:timeStamp];
                        NSLog(@"%d",timeStampObj);

                        am.AlarmID =(int)timeStampObj;
                        NSLog(@"%@",am.AlarmID);

                        idGenereated=TRUE;
                    }

                    app = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
                    [app.newtest setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:am.AlarmID]forKey:@"idtemp"];
                    [app.newtest setObject:app.timerdate forKey:@"iddate"];     

                    notification.userInfo = app.newtest;
                    NSLog(@"notif userinfo:%@",notification.userInfo);
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
                //this line has been commented becuase alarmid was not getting generated

                //}



                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: when u set notification at the time set the sound. but u set after setting notification.it is wrong way to set notification sound

Comment: @Ron i am setting the notification sound when i am scheduling notification

Comment: can u show me ur code when u set

Comment: @Ron when i pass my @"song file name" the song plays.

Comment: why are u using repeat count loop.please check directly assign sound file name in ur program it work or not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5711/discussion-between-ron-and-rani)

Comment: @Ron i want to use repeatCount but u tell me when i set static file name to the sound name property it works ,but when i set any dynamic variable which contains the sound name why does it not play the song

Answer (score 0):

You can refer following links to set up sound.

(1) http://webbuilders.wordpress.com/2009/03/22/iphone-sdk-play-sound-using-audioservicesplaysystemsound-method/

(2) http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/44159-push-notification-play-sounds-other-than-bundle.html

Hope it helps you...